# What is a good duration time for UI animations?

Tags: forms, usability-testing, input-fields, animation, duration

To minimize initial cognitive load, we plan to hide dependent fields within our software by adding animation to show / hide them when called.

I have been looking for articles on duration timing on animation and have not had much luck.

Does anyone have experience with this, or has anyone done any user testing on this?

Here is a link to the animation we are going to be using set at 300ms:

https://www.screencast.com/t/RKuMb97o

Answer (score 2):

According to this article - *[How Fast Should Your UI Animations Be?](http://valhead.com/2016/05/05/how-fast-should-your-ui-animations-be/)* your start point is within a reasonable starting range.

> **200ms to 500ms** is a good range to start with for interface animations.

You can also take into account the guide posted in the article:

[image]

Because, among other reasons, according to the Nielsen Norman Group ([*Response Times - 3 Important Limits*](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/response-times-3-important-limits/)):

> 100ms is perceived as instant, and 1 second is considered the upper limit of a user’s flow of thought.

This is UX we're talking about though, so take into consideration what kind of user is going to use what you're animating instead of just following a guide.

I don't expect you'll find a ton of information on this because it's the kind of thing that, just as you have done, can initially be intuited within a reasonable range of acceptability, and any issues that arise are easy to find with even the most basic user testing.

Comment: "we are going to be using set at 300ms" As a frequent phone user, anything slower than 1/4 second is unacceptably slow because in apps I'm familiar with and know the future layout, quite often my fingers have already tapped where the next button will be, but the app ignores my tap -_-. For opening context menus, seeing where the next list item will be immediately is valuable, making fade-ins more useful than slide-ins. So in frustration, I just disabled all animations system wide wherever possible - functionality trumps fashion.